# Use API on a nw.js application

Tags: google-api, node-webkit, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to consume YouTube Data API v3 from a desktop Node.js application built with [nw.js](http://nwjs.io), but I'm getting an access denied error even though I have enabled the API on Google Console and created a Client ID (for native application).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the API from local files since:

> Applications that use JavaScript to access the YouTube Data API must
>   specify authorized JavaScript origins. The origins identify the
>   domains from which your application can send API requests.
>   ([source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application?hl=en))

As a workaround, you can open a web page hosted on your server, and as long as the page is on an authorized domain it should work.